# Excel xlrd table slice

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

Is there a way to take a table slice instead of row slice or column slice using xlrd.

For the attached table I would like to take rows between 2:5 and columns 3:7

[Excel Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hf6kW.png)

Answer (score 0):

In [xlrd docs](http://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) there is no way to do that. Moreover in Python slice is a one dimensional, but table is a two dimensional by definition. At example in numpy this constraint overcome by usage more complex indexing function (see [Numpy Indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/user/basics.indexing.html)).

You can iterate over cells range use [iteration protocol](http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/iterators.html#the-iteration-protocol) like that:

```
class CellRange:
    def __init__(self, sheet, r1, r2, c1, c2):
        self.sheet = sheet
        self.c1 = c1
        self.c2 = c2
        self.r1 = r1
        self.r2 = r2
        self.cc = self.c1-1 # to get [0,0] item in first next()
        self.rc = self.r1

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        self.cc += 1
        if self.cc > self.c2:
            self.cc = self.c1
            self.rc += 1
        if self.rc > self.r2:
            raise StopIteration()
        return self.sheet.cell_value(self.rc, self.cc)
```

Or with [generator](http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/iterators.html#generators) function:

```
def CellRange(sheet, r1, r2, c1, c2):
    cc = c1
    rc = r1
    while rc <= r2:
        while cc <= c2:
           yield sheet.cell_value(rc, cc)
           cc += 1
        rc += 1
        cc = c1
```

Usage example:

```
for v in CellRange(tablesheet,2,5,3,7):
    print(v)
```

Comment: The remark about slices being one dimensional is correct, but a bit misleading, as Numpy arrays for instance have ”table slicing” by allowing a tuple of slices be given when indexing an array. The class could be expressed as a generator function.